# how to get current directory in maven setting.xml?

Tags: maven

in maven Setting.xml, how do i get current Directory? I Need something like below code
but for current Directory. Any hints are more than welcome!

```
Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository
```

Comment: What do you mean by current directory?

Comment: i mean the directory which Setting.xml resides

Comment: First why do you need that? Furthermore the defaults is exactly as defined as you mentioned..? So I don't understand your question...

Comment: I just want to know if somehing like ${pwd} or ${current.dir} existing for maven

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<localRepository>${user.dir}/.m2</localRepository>
```

It works for me, I have settings.xml file in my project folder itself and using the above path it will create a .m2 directory in project folder itself and download all dependencies there. Make sure running mvn command with --settings options:

```
mvn --settings settings.xml install
```